# Java5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=45 doesn't release heap even when more than 45% of the heap is free

Tags: java, memory

I have a java application with the arguments below but the heap is not getting reclaimed even when the total free space is greater than 45% (can see via visual VM). Is there any reason that the JVM wouldnt free that heap space? The same settings work as expected in Java6. Running Java5 runtime and compile time

```
java -jar -Xmx1024m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=45 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError <myjarname>
```

Comment: Crossposted to Oracle Java Forums: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2311208&tstart=0.

Comment: JVM is greedy, sometimes you need to run major GC twice to get the memory released.

Comment: Since Java 5.0 has been End Of Life for a couple of years, perhaps its time to update to Java 6 or 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We believe we have found an answer to the question. The systems we are running are server class machines with multiple CPUs the JRE was detecting the multiple CPUs and setting the GC to use parallel instead of serial GC which is not compatible with the XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio setting.

Answer (score 2):

The only GC that gives the memory back my system is the G1GC `-XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: This blog entry suggests otherwise - http://javagc.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/java-hotspot-vm-footprint-optimization.html