# JVM is allocating too much space

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I've been runing two tomcat instances clustered with nginx. On my tomcats I run Infinispan as a distributed cache. When I'm inserting about 4mio records into my cache something strange  happens. In picture 1 you can see what I mean. The JVM is allocating more memory than ever needed and won't free after usage.

[image: Heap Tomcat 1]

[image: Heap Tomcat 2]

JVM parameters:

- Xmx8g
- XX:NewRatio=4
- XX:SurvivorRatio=8
- XX:+UseCompressedOops
- XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
- XX:+UseParNewGC
- XX:+DisableExplicitGC
- XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
- XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
- XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
- XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68
- XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20
- XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10

Can you please explain to me why the JVM does not free the allocated memory even though I set the MAXHeapFreeRatio to 20%?

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160445/java5-xxmaxheapfreeratio-45-doesnt-release-heap-even-when-more-than-45-of-th) to see if the issue noticed here might apply to you, and why you're not seeing your memory freed as expected.

tl;dr version is that it seems people have found that a serial GC configuration is the only one that really pays attention to the min/max heap ratio options, but that may be different for your particular case.

[Further reference](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=14) might shed some light on the behavior of the GC.

Comment: I tried a serial GC config but the JVM will not free the memory.